# Projective modules in long exact sequences

Tags: homological-algebra, exact-sequence, projective-module, free-modules

Let $A$ be a commutative ring (with unit), and let $(P_i)_i$ be projective $A$-modules sitting in a long exact sequence of $A$-modules:
$$0 \longrightarrow P_1 \stackrel{f_1}{\longrightarrow} P_2\stackrel{f_2}{\longrightarrow} \cdots \stackrel{f_{r-1}}\longrightarrow P_r \longrightarrow 0.$$
By definition I know that, independently for each $i$, I can find an $A$-module $P_i'$ such that $P_i\oplus P_i'$ is free. But can I find $A$-modules $(P_i')_i$ together with $A$-linear maps $(p_i:P_i'\to P_{i+1}')_i$ such that each $P_i\oplus P_i'$ is free and the sequence
$$0 \longrightarrow P_1\oplus P_1' \xrightarrow{f_1\oplus p_1}P_2\oplus P_2'\xrightarrow{f_2\oplus p_2}\cdots \xrightarrow{f_{r-1}\oplus p_{r-1}} P_r\oplus P_r' \longrightarrow 0 $$
is again a long exact sequence of $A$-modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is easy. Since the original  sequence  is split. You  can suppose it is a short  exact  sequence.$0\rightarrow  P_1\xrightarrow {f_1}P_2\xrightarrow  {f_2}P_3\rightarrow  0$. Suppose $P_1\coprod  Q_1$ and $P_3\coprod  Q_3$ are free modules. Then  $0\rightarrow  P_1\coprod Q_1\rightarrow  P_2\coprod  Q_1\coprod  Q_3\rightarrow  P_3\coprod  Q_3\rightarrow  0$ with natural  morphisms is a short  exact sequence.The middle  is free since  it is split.

Comment: You say « since the original sequence is split », but it is split in the whole category of A-modules, not projective A-modules, right ? So can you assume P_1 and P_3 projective ?

Comment: @Stabilo every  kernel  of the sequence  is projective